# What kind of code creates this function call pattern?

Tags: windows, assembly, windbg, x86-64

While using `WinDbg: u/uf` to disassemble functions in `ntoskrnl.exe` there are functions that are used in system calls and exception handling that have these weird function call patterns and I can't really make out what is going on. For example, the output of `uf nt!KiSystemService` has this in the middle of it:

```
nt!KiSystemService+0x10b:
fffff803`66e07acb e80e010000      call    nt!KiSystemService+0x21e (fffff803`66e07bde)
fffff803`66e07ad0 4883c408        add     rsp,8
fffff803`66e07ad4 e80e010000      call    nt!KiSystemService+0x227 (fffff803`66e07be7)
fffff803`66e07ad9 4883c408        add     rsp,8
fffff803`66e07add e8eeffffff      call    nt!KiSystemService+0x110 (fffff803`66e07ad0)
fffff803`66e07ae2 4883c408        add     rsp,8
fffff803`66e07ae6 e8eeffffff      call    nt!KiSystemService+0x119 (fffff803`66e07ad9)
fffff803`66e07aeb 4883c408        add     rsp,8
fffff803`66e07aef e8eeffffff      call    nt!KiSystemService+0x122 (fffff803`66e07ae2)
fffff803`66e07af4 4883c408        add     rsp,8
fffff803`66e07af8 e8eeffffff      call    nt!KiSystemService+0x12b (fffff803`66e07aeb)
fffff803`66e07afd 4883c408        add     rsp,8
fffff803`66e07b01 e8eeffffff      call    nt!KiSystemService+0x134 (fffff803`66e07af4)

Goes on for many many more lines...
```

I'm pretty sure anyone who has poked around `ntoskrnl.exe` has seen these types of calls before, but I'm not really sure as to what's happening. Is there any explanation as to what kind of C code can cause this kind of ASM code to be compiled, or is this something else from handwritten ASM that's been linked into the executable?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Where did you get the assumption from that this is C code in its original form?

Comment: I don't think it came from a C source, but I thought I may be wrong. That's why I asked `or is this something else from handwritten ASM that's been linked into the executable?`.